# Use UIDatePicker for Calendars other than Gregorian Calendar

Tags: ios, date, calendar, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I've been looking to find a way to use `UIDatePicker` for calendars other than gregorian calendar. Some people suggested to set the calendar property of `UIDatePicker` which I tried but it didn't do much of a good. Some other people suggested using `UIPickerView`.

I was wondering if anyone else has any other suggestions other than these.

Comment: What do you mean setting the `calendar` property "didn't do much"? What *did* it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the only way is to use UIPickerView. UIDatePicker is not meant to be customized